# Problems With PHPCode

Tags: drupal-6, drupal-views

I have an id field that is for example: field_obvious_advantage_value. And this field is inside a div. Now my problem is, when the field is disabled, div remains in its place, naturally with their classes. Anyone knows what the code should be written when the field is not active, div is also disabled?

I wrote the code that is the problem. When placed inside the page, white page and error message shows.

```
<?php if(!empty($node->field_obvious_advantage_value[0]['#value'])){?>
<?php print '<div>'; ?>
<?php print $node->field_obvious_advantage_value; ?>
<?php print '</div>'; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Can you tell me, where is this code wrong?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have a problem with the 'if' statement, try:

```
<?php if(!empty($node->field_obvious_advantage_value[0]['#value'])): ?>
<?php print '<div>'; ?>
<?php print $node->field_obvious_advantage_value; ?>
<?php print '</div>'; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Depending on your setup you maybe able to reduce this to:

```
<? if(!empty($node->field_obvious_advantage_value[0]['#value'])): ?>
<?= '<div>'.$node->field_obvious_advantage_value.'</div>' ?>
<? endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer
I use both methods separately.
My page is not white in any other way. But the field is not visible. Even when the field is there.